# Facebook Messenger Bot: Understanding Export Arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I am trying to learn how to create a facebook Bot.

[I found this amazing article on Medium which illustrates how we can create a messenger bot](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-create-your-very-own-facebook-messenger-bot-with-dialogflow-and-node-js-in-just-one-day-f5f2f5792be5)

In this article, The author tells us to create a verification.js. file inside controllers/verification.js. and paste the following code in it.

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const hubChallenge = req.query[‘hub.challenge’];
  const hubMode = req.query[‘hub.mode’];
  const verifyTokenMatches = (req.query[‘hub.verify_token’] === ‘crowdbotics’);
  if (hubMode && verifyTokenMatches) {
    res.status(200).send(hubChallenge);
  } else {
    res.status(403).end();
  }
};
```

This, I understand to be ES6 Anonymous function which executes immediately? And since we aren't doing anything like

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
```

I am assuming it to be simple Vanilla JavaScript file. Now in our app.js we just import like this `const verificationController = require("./controllers/verficiation.js")`

Now, The question which is bothering me is that how did we passed the arguments to this **`module.exports = (req, res) => {`**

Comment: Without reading the article or knowing anything about that bot, I assume you are going to use `verificationController` as middleware to an express route. This will pass `req` and `res` as parameters to the function

Comment: @Luca in node, If we want implement Middleware, don't we do something like `app.get("/",  function (req, res, next, error) {}` ? this seems to be missing app.get. I don't have much of an experience here, Can you please answer my question in stretch?

Comment: No, you'd use it like `app.get("/", verificationController, (req, res) => {...});` Why don't you finish the tutorial, I bet it's explained

Comment: Also, check your single quotes, `'` is not `‘`

Comment: That was medium copy paster error.
Luca, Thanks a lot, It all make sense now, If you could add your comment in the answer section, I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reading the article or knowing anything about that bot, I assume you are going to use `verificationController` as middleware to an express route, like this:

`app.get("/", verificationController, (req, res) => {...});`

This will pass `req` and `res` as parameters to the function